# Flash CS6 AS3 Selected Device Language

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to detect the **current** language that the user select each time to his keyboard but i cannot. The only information that i can retrieve with Capabilities.languages is the installed languages on the device e.g en-US, en-GB. This is not enough to me because i had to know the current selected language, and the new language every time the user change his selection.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you working with the Flash plugin or with AIR?

Comment: @Brian with AIR...

Comment: OK, you can probably get what you need from a native extension.  How does the user select language settings -- Windows language settings?  Or something specific to your app?

Comment: Windows language settings..

Comment: AFAIK you'll need to run a native extension to look up Windows settings.  I don't think you'll find what you're looking for in any AIR-provided classes.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i 'll check it out!